# Integrity of http using browser

Tags: http, browser, hmac, digest-authentication, integrity

How is it possible to check the integrity of http messages in a way browser can do ?
Actually Digest authentication with "qop=auth-int" would work (because the md5 is also over the body) but unfortunately this is not supported by common webservers (like apache).
Is there a way ?

Comment: TLS is a pretty good way.

Comment: Yes, but Is there an "easier" way only over http not https

Comment: Http in and of itself doesn't support this. You could however use ajax calls to retrieve HMAC-encoded chunks of data, and use javascript to verify the chunks. However then you're trusting javascript, so that's really not very secure. I'd say @minitech's idea is probably the best.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no easier way. HTTPS is built into all browsers and most servers, and doesn't take much (if any) custom implementation at all. Plus, encrypted connections are good. If you absolutely cannot use it, a bit more information about the use case would be helpful. Are you looking for security? Do you have a really bad connection?

Comment: I am looking for a way to test for integrity. Privacy is not wished.